# need help in highlighting a row in a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, highlighting

I am trying to highlight a rows `MSE` in the table  but i am unable to do it

and I am getting a small box at the end of the table. need help to draw a red box around the MSE row in the two tables mentioned below.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the image i have shared i am getting the box at the end. which is wrong

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `tikzmarknode{<name>}{<content>}` and `fit` library:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                tikzmark}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\toprule
               & \multicolumn{9}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
 Optimizer+Loss & Activation & (I32) & (I43) &  (I66) &  (I87) &  (Pg10) &  (Pg20) &  (Pg30) &  (Pg40)  \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\

 \tikzmarknode{A}{MSE}   % <---            
                    & Leaky Relu   & 32.33 & 28.44 & 21.24 & 18.75 & 30.15 & 24.39 & 21.51 
                                           & \tikzmarknode{B}{20.21}  \\  % <---

 DSSIM             & Leaky Relu   & 35.5  & 29.5  & 21.74 & 18.44 & 29.9  & 24.21 & 21.27 & 19.02   \\
 PSNR loss         & Leaky Relu   & 33.45 & 29.3  & 21.4  & 18.96 & 30.41 & 24.48 & 21.64 & 20.53 \\
 MAE               & Leaky Relu   & 32.32 & 28.84 & 21.47 & 18.9  & 29.81 & 24.53 & 21.65 & 20.46 \\
 MAE               & Light Relu   & 33.09 & 29.14 & 21.49 & 19.03 & 28.3  & 24.12 & 21.48 & 20.28 \\
 MAE               & Sine         & 32.73 & 28.47 & 21.19 & 18    & 29.06 & 23.92 & 21.08 & 19.9  \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGrE        & Leaky Relu  & 35.7 & 30.52 & 21.54 & 18.99 & 30.5 & 24.46 & 21.85 & 19.86\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL  & Leaky Relu  & 36.67& 30.4  & 22.44 & 18.92 & 32.59& 27.21 & 24.29 & 22.36\\
 MAE + KLL        & Leaky Relu  & 36.96& 30.61 & 22.41 & 19.26 & 32.66& 27.39 & 24.17 & 22.15\\
 MAE              & Leaky Reku  & 35.7 & 30.18 & 21.54 & 18.83 & 31.72& 24.37 & 21.49 & 20.36\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE + KLL       & Leaky Reku & 39.39 & 32.04 & 23.26 & 19.51 & 34.15 & 27.97 & 23.36 & 21.74\\
 MAE + 0.5*KLL   & Leaky Reku & 38.4  & 31.11 & 22.51 & 19.62 & 33.26 & 25.53 & 22.63 & 21.14\\
 MAE + 0.75*KLL  & Leaky Reku & 38.41 & 32.54 & 22.5  & 19.27 & 34.13 & 26.13 & 23.68 & 21.79\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL& Leaky Reku & 38.98 & 31.74 & 22.39 & 19.63 & 34.08 & 27.33 & 23.25 & 21.45\\
 MAE + MGrE      & Leaky Reku & 35.82 & 29.7  & 22.15 & 19.44 & 31.8  & 25.3  & 22.01 & 20.78\\
 \midrule
               & \multicolumn{9}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
 Optimizer+Loss & Activation & (Pr10) &  (Pr20) &  (Pr30) &  (Pr40) &  (Ps025) &  (Ps05) &  (Ps1) &    \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\
 MSE                 & Leaky Relu   & 27.76 & 22.43 & 19.97 & 18.54 & 34.97 & 33.34 & 30.24 \\
 DSSIM               & Leaky Relu   & 28.16 & 22.74 & 19.15 & 17.55 & 33.45 & 30.16 & 27.37  \\
 PSNR loss           & Leaky Relu   & 28.18 & 22.45 & 20.03 & 18.53 & 35.71 & 34.94 & 30.44 \\
 MAE                 & Leaky Relu   & 27.78 & 22.6 & 20.39 & 18.59 & 37.77 &34.19 & 30.87 \\
 MAE                 & Light Relu   & 27.68 & 22.41 & 20.2 & 18.45 & 36.46 &33.93 &30.1 \\
 MAE                 & Sine         & 27.09 & 21.96 & 19.72 & 18.24 & 34 & 31.57 & 28.57 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGrE              & Leaky Relu & 28.21 & 22.26 & 20.22 & 18.63 & 37.24 & 34.87 & 30.97\\
 MAE + MGE + KLL         & Leaky Relu & 29.46 & 24.11 & 21.32 & 19.04 &36.85 & 34.44 & 31.5\\
 MAE + KLL               & Leaky Relu & 29.49 & 24.09 & 21.23 & 19.3 & 37.97 & 35.55 & 31.74\\
 MAE                     & Leaky Relu & 28.41 & 22.46 & 19.85 & 18.41 & 37.32 & 35.04 & 30.91\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE + KLL              & Leaky Relu & 29.96 & 24.43 & 20.97 & 19.2 & 39.72 & 36.78 & 32.92\\
 MAE + 0.5*KLL          & Leaky Relu & 29.76 & 23.18 & 20.71 & 18.9 & 39.93 & 36.52 & 32.91\\
 MAE + 0.75*KLL         & Leaky Relu & 30.29 & 24.11 & 20.94 & 19.28 & 40.12 & 36.83 & 33.18\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL       & Leaky Relu & 30.3 & 23.93 & 21.1 & 18.98 & 39.72 & 36.06 & 32.71\\
 MAE + MGrE             & Leaky Relu & 28.95 &22.75 & 20.26& 18.96 & 39.62 & 35.54 & 31.16\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[draw=red, fit=(A) (B)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\smallskip

\footnotesize
MSE: Mean Square Error; MAE: Mean Absolute Error; MGE: Mean Gradient Error
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For result you need to compile MWE at least twice .

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

I have replaced the environment `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` and I have added a line before the code of the row to highlight:

`\Block[draw=red,rounded-corners]{1-*}{}`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hp]
\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\toprule
               & \multicolumn{9}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
 Optimizer+Loss & Activation & (I32) & (I43) &  (I66) &  (I87) &  (Pg10) &  (Pg20) &  (Pg30) &  (Pg40)  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\
\Block[draw=red,rounded-corners]{1-*}{}  % <-----
MSE                & Leaky Relu   & 32.33 & 28.44 & 21.24 & 18.75 & 30.15 & 24.39 & 21.51 & 20.21  \\  

 DSSIM             & Leaky Relu   & 35.5  & 29.5  & 21.74 & 18.44 & 29.9  & 24.21 & 21.27 & 19.02   \\
 PSNR loss         & Leaky Relu   & 33.45 & 29.3  & 21.4  & 18.96 & 30.41 & 24.48 & 21.64 & 20.53 \\
 MAE               & Leaky Relu   & 32.32 & 28.84 & 21.47 & 18.9  & 29.81 & 24.53 & 21.65 & 20.46 \\
 MAE               & Light Relu   & 33.09 & 29.14 & 21.49 & 19.03 & 28.3  & 24.12 & 21.48 & 20.28 \\
 MAE               & Sine         & 32.73 & 28.47 & 21.19 & 18    & 29.06 & 23.92 & 21.08 & 19.9  \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGrE        & Leaky Relu  & 35.7 & 30.52 & 21.54 & 18.99 & 30.5 & 24.46 & 21.85 & 19.86\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL  & Leaky Relu  & 36.67& 30.4  & 22.44 & 18.92 & 32.59& 27.21 & 24.29 & 22.36\\
 MAE + KLL        & Leaky Relu  & 36.96& 30.61 & 22.41 & 19.26 & 32.66& 27.39 & 24.17 & 22.15\\
 MAE              & Leaky Reku  & 35.7 & 30.18 & 21.54 & 18.83 & 31.72& 24.37 & 21.49 & 20.36\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE + KLL       & Leaky Reku & 39.39 & 32.04 & 23.26 & 19.51 & 34.15 & 27.97 & 23.36 & 21.74\\
 MAE + 0.5*KLL   & Leaky Reku & 38.4  & 31.11 & 22.51 & 19.62 & 33.26 & 25.53 & 22.63 & 21.14\\
 MAE + 0.75*KLL  & Leaky Reku & 38.41 & 32.54 & 22.5  & 19.27 & 34.13 & 26.13 & 23.68 & 21.79\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL& Leaky Reku & 38.98 & 31.74 & 22.39 & 19.63 & 34.08 & 27.33 & 23.25 & 21.45\\
 MAE + MGrE      & Leaky Reku & 35.82 & 29.7  & 22.15 & 19.44 & 31.8  & 25.3  & 22.01 & 20.78\\
 \midrule
               & \multicolumn{9}{c}{PSNR}\\
\cmidrule{3-10}
 Optimizer+Loss & Activation & (Pr10) &  (Pr20) &  (Pr30) &  (Pr40) &  (Ps025) &  (Ps05) &  (Ps1) &    \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Adam}\\
 MSE                 & Leaky Relu   & 27.76 & 22.43 & 19.97 & 18.54 & 34.97 & 33.34 & 30.24 \\
 DSSIM               & Leaky Relu   & 28.16 & 22.74 & 19.15 & 17.55 & 33.45 & 30.16 & 27.37  \\
 PSNR loss           & Leaky Relu   & 28.18 & 22.45 & 20.03 & 18.53 & 35.71 & 34.94 & 30.44 \\
 MAE                 & Leaky Relu   & 27.78 & 22.6 & 20.39 & 18.59 & 37.77 &34.19 & 30.87 \\
 MAE                 & Light Relu   & 27.68 & 22.41 & 20.2 & 18.45 & 36.46 &33.93 &30.1 \\
 MAE                 & Sine         & 27.09 & 21.96 & 19.72 & 18.24 & 34 & 31.57 & 28.57 \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger}\\
 MAE + MGrE              & Leaky Relu & 28.21 & 22.26 & 20.22 & 18.63 & 37.24 & 34.87 & 30.97\\
 MAE + MGE + KLL         & Leaky Relu & 29.46 & 24.11 & 21.32 & 19.04 &36.85 & 34.44 & 31.5\\
 MAE + KLL               & Leaky Relu & 29.49 & 24.09 & 21.23 & 19.3 & 37.97 & 35.55 & 31.74\\
 MAE                     & Leaky Relu & 28.41 & 22.46 & 19.85 & 18.41 & 37.32 & 35.04 & 30.91\\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ranger21}\\
 MAE + KLL              & Leaky Relu & 29.96 & 24.43 & 20.97 & 19.2 & 39.72 & 36.78 & 32.92\\
 MAE + 0.5*KLL          & Leaky Relu & 29.76 & 23.18 & 20.71 & 18.9 & 39.93 & 36.52 & 32.91\\
 MAE + 0.75*KLL         & Leaky Relu & 30.29 & 24.11 & 20.94 & 19.28 & 40.12 & 36.83 & 33.18\\
 MAE + MGrE + KLL       & Leaky Relu & 30.3 & 23.93 & 21.1 & 18.98 & 39.72 & 36.06 & 32.71\\
 MAE + MGrE             & Leaky Relu & 28.95 &22.75 & 20.26& 18.96 & 39.62 & 35.54 & 31.16\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\smallskip

\footnotesize
MSE: Mean Square Error; MAE: Mean Absolute Error; MGE: Mean Gradient Error
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]